# Auto Increment in Django with views.py

Tags: mysql, django, django-views

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    m = sql.connect(host="localhost",user="root",password="admin@123", database= "ticketsys")
    cursor = m.cursor()

    ticketid = request.POST['ticketid']
    email = request.POST['email']
    username = request.POST.get('username')
    checkbox = request.POST['checkbox']
    adult = request.POST['adult']
    fromstation = request.POST['fromstation']
    tostation = request.POST['tostation']
    rate = request.POST["rate"]
    date = request.POST.get('date')
    usermessage = request.POST['usermessage']


    c = "insert into ticketsys.ticketgen values('{}','{}','{}','{}','{}','{}','{}','{}','{}','{}')".format(ticketid,email,username,checkbox,adult,fromstation,tostation,rate ,date, usermessage)
    cursor.execute(c)
    m.commit()

    return render(request, 'account/ticketconf.html')


else:
    return render(request, 'account/ticket.html')
```

Here, ticket id is auto-increment but its showing me error.

```
1366 (HY000): Incorrect integer value: '' for column 'ticketid' at row 1
```

What is best way to solve this problem. so that without creating model I can be able to post my data in mysql.

[SQL- Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eg010.png)

Comment: Any particular reason you don't want to create a model?

Comment: If `ticketid` is auto-increment then I think you don't have to set `ticketid` by yourself.